# Maple- Approximation to the smallest positive solution

Tags: maple

Part of my first year university degree, I need to work with the Maple software.

I have this question.

Find an approximation to the smallest positive solution to

$$(-38/25)*sin(9/10*x)=(13/25)*exp(-16*x/25)$$

Correct to 10 sig.figs

No matter what I do, I don't seem to get the correct answer.

Initially, I got a negative answer but then I sent the bound of x from 0 to infinity. Still getting the wrong answer.

This is my best attempt so far.

fsolve((-38/25)*sin(9/10*x)=(13/25)*exp(-16*x/25),x,x=0..infinity);

10.47244230

All help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
restart;
expr1 := -38/25*sin(9/10*x):
expr2 := 13/25*exp(-16/25*x):

P1 := plot(expr1,x=0..10,color=blue):
P2 := plot(expr2,x=0..10,color=red):
plots:-display(P1,P2,view=-2..2);
```

[image]

The purpose of creating the plot is to allow you visually
discover a range for x between which the two curves intersect
only once.

For example you can see that they intersect only once
between x=0 and x=5.

Thus you can figure out, by visual inspection of the plot,
a suitable range to use when calling fsolve.

```
fsolve(expr1-expr2, x=0..5);

                      3.530355063
```

Here are some other ways,

```
RootFinding:-NextZero(unapply(expr1-expr2,x), 0.0);

                      3.530355062

Student:-Calculus1:-Roots(expr1-expr2, x=0..10, numeric);

               [3.530355063, 6.976944937]

min(%);

                      3.530355063
```

Comment: I see what you mean. When I set the bound to infinity, I didn't recognise there were 2 points of intersection, hence I was not getting the smallest value. Thank you for the graph. Really explained it well. In fact now trying it again, there was nothing wrong with my input, just bounds were incorrect.

Comment: For the range `x=0..infinity` there are an infinite number of intersections, not just 2. Also, the given plot (or a plot of the difference) shows that the roots of `expr1-expr2` are close to the roots of `expr1`. And it turns out that using a root of `expr1` as an initial-point for `fsolve` will allow it to find the corresponding close root of `expr1-expr2`. But we know the roots of `expr1`, which are `k*10/9*Pi, k=1,2,...`. And indeed calling `fsolve(expr1-expr2,x=10/9*Pi);` returns the desired first point of intersection.